# 403 error despite having a 200 ok response on login Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I'm running into a weird situation.

Here's what I know:

In order to get it to log in, I need to send the credentials as a `x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request. User provides correct credentials, it passes and provides the user with an access token and a refresh token, if not, it fails and does not provide any of those tokens - which is what one would expect.

Now, once logged in and I try to access a resource - in this case it's the list of users I have - it fails with a 403 forbidden error. I'm currently using PostMan to test the API. The initial `POST` request I made after login is with a `Bearer Token` authorisation where in I use the access token. It fails. After debugging my code on Spring Boot:

```
@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("api/login") || request.getServletPath().equals("/api/token/refresh")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);

            if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                    // TODO: Refactor this to a utility class.
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
                    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
                    String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    stream(roles).forEach(role -> {
                        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                    });
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    log.error("Error logging in: " + exception.getMessage());

                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("error_message", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found that `token` returns null. OK... let's try sending it as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead. `token` picks up the token sent... Great! stepped in all the way through the code after `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` and get to `requiresAuthentication()` in Spring Boots code... this returns `false` which is good... This is looking really good.

However, return to Postman - `Status: 403 Forbidden`. Oh - how? Looking at the logs for Spring Boot I picked out the following which is related to my url entrypoint:

```
2022-04-16 08:36:47.267 DEBUG 21000 --- [nio-8102-exec-4] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1683533175<open>)] after transaction
2022-04-16 08:36:47.275 DEBUG 21000 --- [nio-8102-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since no credentials provided
2022-04-16 08:36:47.275 DEBUG 21000 --- [nio-8102-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2022-04-16 08:36:47.275 DEBUG 21000 --- [nio-8102-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-04-16 08:36:47.275 DEBUG 21000 --- [nio-8102-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2022-04-16 08:36:47.285 DEBUG 21000 --- [nio-8102-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
```

Being new to this, I'm not sure how I should proceed to fix this.

EDIT:

This is my current security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Lazy
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**", "/api/login/**", "/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/save/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/role/assign-to-user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));
        http.addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    protected CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return source;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationFilter:

```
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        log.info("Username: \"" + username + "\", password: \"" + password + "\"");

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        // TODO: Generate secret key that is a little more secure than this.
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
        String accessToken = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        String refreshToken  = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);

        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("access_token", accessToken);
        tokens.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);

        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: you do know that spring security comes with a built in JWTFilter, so all your custom code is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that AuthorizationFilter creates authorities but then does not set them in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Your security matchers require an authority.